# deleted logical partitions - how to restore data?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I had following partitions: [NTFS][NTFS]{ext3, ext4, ext4, SWAP}. The logical Drive was deleted, and a small primary Partition created at the end of disk (smaller than the SWAP). Is there any way to recover some data from the ext* partitions?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/167432/recover-a-partition and many, many others...

Comment: This one's about a **damaged extended** partition.

Comment: And? Your extended partition is not 'damaged'? The solution is the same. Basically the solution to all questions regarding damaged/vanished/overwritten partitions is the same.

Comment: I'ts way easier to restore a primary partition than logical ones. At the moment I'm trying a deepscan with testdisk, and will report if succeed or failed.

Answer (score 1):

First rule, **don't do anything directly on source disk**. Please, use `ddrescue` to image your hdd.

Second, do rescuing on your hdd image with `testdisk`, `Sleuth Kit`, or any application that support working with image.

Good luck.